# kubernetes how to copy a cfg file into container before contaner running?

Tags: kubernetes

My service need a cfg file which need to be changed before containers start running. So it is not suitable to pack the cfg into docker image.
I need to copy from cluster to container, and then the service in container start and reads this cfg.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think for your use-case , [Init Containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) might be the best fit. Init Containers are like small scripts that you can run before starting your own containers in kubernetes pod , they must exit. You can have this config file updated in shared Persistent Volume between your Init container and your container.

Following article gives a nice example as to how this can be done

https://dev.to/jmarhee/getting-started-with-kubernetes-initcontainers-and-volume-pre-population-j83

**UPDATE :**

I found another answer from stackoverflow which might be related and give you a better approach in handling this

[can i use a configmap created from an init container in the pod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50012601/can-i-use-a-configmap-created-from-an-init-container-in-the-pod)

Comment: the medium article link is broken

Comment: More info: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-initialization/#create-a-pod-that-has-an-init-container

Answer (score 8):

An example

ouput

```
NAME          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
cassandra-0   1/1     Running   0          70s
[root@green--1 ~]# k exec -it cassandra-0 -n green -- /bin/bash
root@cassandra-0:/# ls /config/cassandra/
cassandra.yaml
```

How the directory is shared

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: cassandra
  namespace: green
  labels:
    app: cassandra
spec:
  serviceName: cassandra
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: cassandra
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: cassandra
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 1800
      initContainers:
       - name: copy
         image: busybox:1.28
         command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "cp /config/cassandra.yaml /config/cassandra/"]
         volumeMounts:
         - name: tmp-config
           mountPath: /config/cassandra/
         - name: cassandraconfig
           mountPath: /config/
      containers:
      - name: cassandra
        #image: gcr.io/google-samples/cassandra:v13
        image: cassandra:3.11.6
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        #command: [ "/bin/sh","-c","su cassandra && mkdir -p /etc/cassandra/ && cp /config/cassandra/cassandra.yaml /etc/cassandra/" ]
        ports:
        - containerPort: 7000
          name: intra-node
        - containerPort: 7001
          name: tls-intra-node
        - containerPort: 7199
          name: jmx
        - containerPort: 9042
          name: cql
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: "500m"
            memory: 4Gi
          requests:
            cpu: "500m"
            memory: 4Gi
        securityContext:
          capabilities:
            add:
              - IPC_LOCK
        lifecycle:
          postStart:
            exec:
              command: 
              - /bin/sh
              - -c
              - "cp /config/cassandra/cassandra.yaml /etc/cassandra/"
          preStop:
            exec:
              command: 
              - /bin/sh
              - -c
              - nodetool drain
        env:
          - name: MAX_HEAP_SIZE
            value: 1G
          - name: HEAP_NEWSIZE
            value: 100M
          - name: CASSANDRA_SEEDS
            value: "cassandra-0.cassandra.green.svc.cluster.local"
          - name: CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME
            value: "green"
          - name: CASSANDRA_DC
            value: "ee1-green"
          - name: CASSANDRA_RACK
            value: "Rack1-green"
          - name: POD_IP
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: status.podIP
        readinessProbe:
          exec:
            command:
            - /bin/bash
            - -c
            - /ready-probe.sh
          initialDelaySeconds: 15
          timeoutSeconds: 55

        volumeMounts:
        - name: cassandradata
          mountPath: /cassandra_data

        - name: tmp-config
          mountPath: /config/cassandra/

      volumes: 
      - name: cassandraconfig
        configMap:
          name: cassandraconfig
      - name: tmp-config
        emptyDir: {}
      # 1 Creating a volume to move date from init container to main container without making mount ReadOnly

  # These are converted to volume claims by the controller
  # and mounted at the paths mentioned above.

  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: cassandradata
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      storageClassName: rook-ceph-block
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 5Gi
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use ConfigMap. Create a config map resource and config your container to load the config map accordingly. You container will then be able to load those variables from its environment variable.

Here is the reference: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/