# My kubernetes deployment not work as expected

Tags: kubernetes

I want to download the cfg file to container and then use exec to replace my process, so that when my process crashes, the container can restart automatically because my process has pid 1. I can't pack the cfg into image due to some reason. The container is created successfully but it stucks and myExec doesn't start. Here is my yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    run: myPod
  name: myPod
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: myPod
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        run: myPod
    spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - sh
        - -c
        - wget http://x.x.x.x:12345/cfg.ini -O /etc/cfg.ini && exec myExec -c /etc/cfg.ini
        image: myimage
        name: myPod
        resources: {}
status: {}
```

Comment: What events do you get when do `kubectl describe po yourpod`?

Comment: I believe the better approach would be to use Init Containers to populate your configuration file in a shared volume. See this stackoverflow answer which deals with somewhat similar situation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55291850/kubernetes-how-to-copy-a-cfg-file-into-container-before-contaner-running/55294047#55294047

Comment: ...or put the configuration into a ConfigMap, which is designed to be injected into containers.

Comment: Can you check log using "kubectl logs POD_ID -n NAMESPACE" please change pod_id and namespace as per your config.